# Recursively get file and directory name without exception in VIsta and win7

Tags: c#

I [have a program which] recursively searches my computer drives to list all the files available but when the program runs, it throws a runtime exception and stops. I am not a fan of nested directory search, you know. I have no clue what should I do to get all files and drives names printed in my `ListView`.

I run this program on Vista and Win7 and it fails on both.

Comment: please show some code and the error message(s)/exception(s)

Comment: this is not a question but a statement

Comment: I run it on my own machine, there is no network . The source code I pick from MS website'MSDN libriry, there is nothing new I add it,

Answer (score 2):

You don't show your code, but I suspect you are not handling any possible exceptions. There are folders/files in Windows that you cannot search due to permission issue (even if you are running as an admin). In those cases, there would be an exception raised which would need to be handled gracefully.

Comment: i would agree with CodeNaked.. add exception handling, and log the exception details to see where all the recursive logic fails.. manually try to go to these paths and we can analyze better.

Comment: @Black - Yeah, you are obviously missing some exception handling. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx) is an example with some exception handling, but looks like the call to GetDirectories would need to be wrapped in a try-catch also.